# How Do I Seperate Values In Argv For Beginners?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just began coding recently and I am using a book called: "Learn Python the Hard Way". I came accros an exercise where I have to import sys and use argv.
The book uses python 2.7 and there have been a few things that are different but I have found my way around it, however not with the argv because I don't know how to split the words I want the argv to be.

Looking on the internet, people are giving way too complicated fixes that my beginner coder brain can't handle yet.

```py
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv  # <--------- Here is the problem, I can't make it 2 values

prompt = '>'


print("Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script))

print("I'd like to ask you a few questions.")

print("Do you like me %s?" % user_name)

likes = input(prompt)

print("Where do you live %s?" % user_name)

lives = input(prompt)

print("What kind of computer do you have?")

computer = input(prompt)

print( """
Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure where that is.
And you have a %r computer. Nice.
""" % (likes, lives, computer))
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Take a look at the `argparse` module; there's little need to work with `sys.argv` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Before you can unpack `argv` into exactly two values, you have to be sure that there actually *are* exactly (or at least) two values in the list.

```
if len(argv) < 2:
    sys.exit("Too few arguments")

script, user_name = argv[:2]  # Only unpack the first two elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are passed in through the command line- if you are using windows it would be power shell, or mac then terminal, it would look something like this-(and forgive the power shell refer):

```
[Root folder\mystuff]python ex14.py(arg1) name(arg2)
```

Then hit enter. It would then pass the two arguments to the script and put them in the variables. Hope this helps. 
This is it quoted from the source:

```
$ python ex14.py **zed**
>>> Hi **zed**, I'm the ex14.py script.
```